# How do I clear all 45 waves in Big Time Gangsta?

Tags: android, big-time-gangsta

Has anyone cleared all 45 waves in [Big Time Gangsta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glu.android.brawler&hl=en)? I'm playing the game without buying any credits (I think that model is silly) so I can only purchase items that do not require credits.

I have come up with some fighting strategies that help my to clear the first 10 waves without too much effort or loss of health but I think beyond that I'll have to stock up on equipment like health kits.

What does it take to clear all 45 waves?

Comment: you can earn 15 creds per day watching 15-30 sec video to buy more powerful guns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need smove no matter what. I got lucky with credit lottos and my threesome is 500 hp, 450 hp, and 250 hp, to beat all 45 waves you have to be completely focused with at least 20 minutes of time on your hand. To beat all 45 waves I equipped the three characters I used with 100 medium health and 70 medium damage. I used one credit weapon because honestly, without at least one credit item or thing, you're screwed. On to the battle: mow down the first three at the start of the wave then as more and more start coming take them down one at a time alternating quickly between shooters firing at one target. This will kill him a lot faster. If your health starts getting low use a health pack and use damage increases whenever you can. Around wave 40 the enemies get lower health but increased damage. That isn't too hard if you can dispatch them quickly enough. Wave 45, no matter how good you are, unless you have 100% credit weapons and the three best characters in the game you will have at least one of your thugs gunned down.  After this target the weakest enemies and hope for the best. I lost 8/11 times at the arena using this method, so don't expect it to work at first.

Comment: nice. So obviously I need health and damage boosts, but what about accuracy, do you think less damage but higher accuracy is better or just damage alone. I'm using Genx Hawk on all 5 of my charactors. I bought the female for 60 creds (450hp). I was able to win almost 80 creds in the slot machine.

Answer (score 2):

Ridiculous.

Get free cred by watching free videos, downloading free apps, etc. Don't buy a thing, don't spend a dime. Wait until you have the guins and equipment to mount a single successful assault.

Gun up with at least the Law Elite; The Oma 7 is even better. Health is the only thing that REALLY matters; I suggest at least 30 medium per character for the first few times (don't forget to use all six allowed character spaces). Back it up with your choice of damage, pillz, etc.

After yout first successful assault, subsequent times become easier and easier - you now have Gold Hammers to make it a LOT easier. I also like to load up with small med - 35 per person (they're cheap) and run it up to level 44 and quit. $42K in the bank for only about $6K.

Comment: I downloaded all the games they wanted me to. Got those creds (also earned a bunch by gambling) but they didn't offer any more free cred offers after that.

Answer (score 0):

7/9
I think the arena might have gotten tougher. I tried this today with 285000$ on my account. Most went into healing and defence. At lvl 35+ i had to use like 4 medium health pr wave pr. char and 2 medium defence. Thats atleast 24k and probably more pr. wave. I had to quit at lvl 42 cuss otherwise all my guys would die. Will try again at 500k.

26/10
Okay, so i tried this again with 472.000$ on my account. My tactic was more thought out this time, so i was sure it was gonna work. One thing i did wrong last time, was never using small health power-ups. By using small health+medium, you can get to somewhere around 35-40. At lvl 42 you for sure need to switch to medium health and medium defence. I've made a list of how many enemies come pr. wave and what weapons they are using if someone is interrested. The six guys i used were Biddy Big(500hp), Smoove(500hp), Chillz(675hp), Caliente(550hp), Mikey D(250hp) and the 200hp guy. Four of them with GenX Hawk and two with MP5. At the end i had like 120.000$ left and a gold hammer in my stash. For the last four waves i had eight medium health and four medium defence on each. When the arena finished i only had two guys left standing. Wave 42-45 are 12-13 guys with Steyer and other cred weapons.